# Mac version of man doesn't have the -u option. How could I rebuild man's database of commands?

Tags: mac, command-line, unix

In Linux, the following rebuilds, or updates, `man`'s database of commands:

```
> man -u
```

But that option does not exist in Mac OS X's BSD version. How could I update `man`'s database of commands on the Mac?

Answer (score 1):

The `man` command actually doesn't have a database of commands except when mimicking `apropos` with the `-k` command. The `-u` option in Gnu `man` just checks the cache used by `man` to speed up some lookups.

The only database is the `whatis` database. It is used by  the `whatis` and `apropos` commands. It can be created or recreated by the `makewhatis` command - `sudo /usr/libexec/makewhatis`.